# FFmpeg CLI - swap RTMP source using ZMQ (zmqsend)

Tags: ffmpeg, stream, zeromq, live, rtmp

My setup is as follows:

- Nginx with the RTMP module
- Multiple RTMP stream pairs, each one with a primary and backup RTMP endpoint (so streaming to  rtmp://localhost/main/$STREAM_NAME and rtmp://localhost/backup/$STREAM_NAME)
- Using the Nginx RTMP `module exec_publish` and `exec_publish_done` hooks, I push either main or backup to an FFmpeg CLI proc that restreams it to a remote RTMP endpoint (Wowza server in this case, though it's not very relevant to my question)

My problem is that currently, if the main stream is stopped, I have to stop the FFmpeg CLI process that restreams to Wowza and start another with a new input source (the backup stream). This often causes issues on the Wowza side so I'm looking for a way to avoid that.

After some research, I found that FFmpeg encapsulated ZMQ support but it seems documentation is very sparse. Is it possible to send a message to the running FFmpeg process to alert it that it must change its source to a different RTMP stream?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 5):

In case it's of interest to anyone, I solved my problem in a different way.
I now use named pipes, like so:

```sh
PIPE_FILE= /path/to/pip/file
mkfifo $PIPE_FILE
exec 7<>$PIPE_FILE
ffmpeg -nostdin  -i /path/to/source -acodec copy -vcodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts pipe:1 > $PIPE_FILE
```

`/path/to/source` can be a media file on the FS or an RTMP stream, for that matter.

I then re-stream from the pipe to the final RTMP endpoint:

```sh
ffmpeg -re -i $PIPE_FILE -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -r 25 -g 50 -f flv $RTMP_ENDPOINT
```

When `$PIPE_FILE` stops receiving data (i.e - when streaming stops or, in the case of sending data from a local media file, when EOF is reached), I immediately launch a different FFmpeg CLI proc and feed the pipe data from the backup media file/stream.

That keeps the re-streaming FFmpeg CLI proc continuously up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting approach. I've got something similar. Instead of the Pipe, I'm using another local rtmp destination.

I've got an nginx rtmp setup with 3 apps. One is the main app, another the backup app, and another is the distribute app.
So I send the main stream to the main app from my streaming software.
I have a `ffmpeg` process running:

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/main/stream1 -c copy rtmp://127.0.0.1/distribute/stream1`

If this process breaks due to the input shutting down, I run a similar command to pull input from the backup:

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/backup/stream1 -c copy rtmp://127.0.0.1/distribute/stream1`

From my distribute app I stream to my external outputs.

Only issue here is that I get the non-monotonous DTS error after the switch, so I've had to add a few flags when streaming from distribute to my outputs. The command is:

`ffmpeg -fflags +genpts+igndts+ignidx -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/distribute/stream1 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -r 25 -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv $RTMP_ENDPOINT`

I've noticed I get some warnings in the `ffmpeg` process when I switch, if the main and backup streams are coming in with different x264 profiles, let's say one is on High and the other on Baseline or Main.

Comment: I've originally gone with that approach, myself. I've used https://github.com/ThePooN/rtmp-fallback as a starting point. However, `ffmpeg` CLI crashed often while switching and also, it's more expensive from a HW resource perspective.

Comment: Curious to know if you received any warnings in your ffmpeg process about memory management, reference count etc. if your inputs were using different encoding profiles? Also what happens when you're writing into the pipe but not reading from it for a while? When you finally do start reading, does it give you the current data, or something written in earlier? And finally, did you get any PTS or DTS errors, because the second RTMP basically starts with a zero timestamp again?

Comment: Did not get any mem management related errors; are you asking because you did? If so, what sort of errors?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I initially got non-monotonous DTS error. Essentially, when shifting to the backup stream (since it starts with a different timestamp), the ffmpeg process taking this as an input sees a sudden shift in timestamps. To solve those, I had to add  -fflags +genpts+igndts+ignidx -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1    Did you add any of these? I'd really like to remove these as I do not understand how they function. Also the mem management errors were of the sort : illegal memory management control operation 12 illegal modification_of_pic_nums_idc